# GIS Survey Line Plans

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, line, mapwindow, land-survey

Has anyone ever heard of any tools in either Arcmap, QGIS, Mapwindow GIS etc, that could create a line plan (Survey Lines) across a polygon (Survey Area)?

A form of input such as distance between lines and minimum length would hopefully be required. If this tool could be tailored to create the shortest, so most efficient line plan, then that would be even better. Obviously a form of automation rather than just manually offsetting poly-lines is required- as that can get very monotonous over large areas!

[image]

The image attached shows the kind of output I need, however the Survey Areas are usually much more irregular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you have an area as a polygon and want to draw regular lines over the polygon. What you could do is use QGis "create vector grid" under vector->research.

Answer (score 2):

The ArcGIS solution is called [Create Fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000). You can specify the origin of the grid, a rotation to better align it to a shape, the cell size, and constrain it to your survey area.